# Нужно что бы бот раздавал номера по порядку при определенном запросе

Tags: python, telebot

Решил написать простейшего бота, для учета путевых листов. Нужно что бы бот раздавал номера по порядку при определенном запросе.
НО просто это почемуто работать хочет)
Возможно дело в том что глобальную переменную нельзя изменять в функции, но мозгов не хватает)
Пробовал разные костыли и глупости но решения нет.

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('-')

m = 152

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "1":
        m += 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'резервирую за вами № {m}')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

[image: вот как то так это должно выглядеть]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('-')

m = 152

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    global m
    if message.text == "1":
        m += 1
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'резервирую за вами № {m}')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```